# Cloudera: Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat on CDH 5.14 cluster installation on singleNode from agents

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, agent, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install cloudera CDH 5.14.0. and facing below error during Cluster Installation.

```
Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.

Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager Server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are not in use on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added. (Some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
If Use TLS Encryption for Agents is enabled in Cloudera Manager (Administration -> Settings -> Security), ensure that /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini has use_tls=1 on the host being added. Restart the corresponding agent and click the Retry link here.
```

Detail Log:

```
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO Neither verify_cert_file nor verify_cert_dir are configured. Not performing validation of server certificates in HTTPS communication. These options can be configured in this agent's config.ini file to enable certificate validation. 
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO Agent Logging Level: INFO 
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO No command line vars 
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO Found database jar: /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar 
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO Missing database jar: /usr/share/java/oracle-connector-java.jar (normal, if you're not using this database type) 
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO Found database jar: /usr/share/cmf/lib/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar 
>>[28/Jan/2018 10:30:44 +0000] 12771 MainThread agent INFO Agent starting as pid 12771 user root(0) group root(0). 
END (0) 
end of agent logs. 
scm agent restarted
```

Local ubuntu host details:

```
chaithu@chaithu:~$ hostname
chaithu
chaithu@chaithu:~$ hostname -f
chaithu
chaithu@chaithu:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   chaithu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

chaithu@chaithu:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7180            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1353/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7182            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1353/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12930/python2.7 
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1162/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7190          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12930/python2.7 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1031/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12930/python2.7 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5112/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1077/postgres   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19001         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1632/python     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12771/python2.7 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1434/postgres   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1045/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1441/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::4434                 :::*                    LISTEN      12930/python2.7 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1031/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::7191                 :::*                    LISTEN      12930/python2.7 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      5112/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::7432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1434/postgres   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57656           0.0.0.0:*                           902/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           5113/cups-browsed
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           2703/chrome     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           902/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39330           0.0.0.0:*                           1162/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7191            0.0.0.0:*                           12930/python2.7 
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1162/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1117/dhclient   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                2703/chrome     
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                902/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::46382                :::*                                902/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::7191                 :::*                                12930/python2.7
```

I am trying to install CDH only on single node local machine.  Do let me know if any more info required.

Comment: I think you need to remove `127.0.1.1   chaithu`  from hosts file, but are you using the quickstart VM?

Comment: I am not using VM, Trying to install on my own system running with ubuntu.

Comment: Your question only mentions the agent... Is Cloudera Manager running? Can you show your agent configuration?